# Is there a convenient way to input only one character by some Qt widget?

Tags: c++, qt

Is there any convenient way to input one `QChar` character by some Qt widget? Using `QLineEdit` need to convert `QString` to `QChar` and do some validation? Any char validator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either you should use QLineEdit::setMaxLength() or set a validator with QLineEdit::setValidator();

```
QRegExpValidator rv = new QRegExpValidator(QRegExp("^.$"));
lineEdit->setValidator(rv);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the maxLength property to limit the input to one character:

```
lineEdit->setMaxLength(1);
```

For validation beyond that, implement your own [QValidator](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qvalidator.html).